# Automatically pull packages on provisioning

Tags: octopus-deploy

We're hosting on EC2.  I've read this article [here](http://octopusdeploy.com/blog/auto-provision-ec2-instances-with-tentacle-installed) for provisioning tentacles.  Is there a script which will then tell that provisioned server to grab the latest packages (from the latest release of the environment it's provisioned for)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "latest package"? Are you wanting the tentacle to immediately go and install the latest release of an application by pulling it from the Octopus Deploy server?

Comment: Yes to your assumption.

Comment: You'd have to initiate a deployment in Octopus Deploy. You could do this by writing a PowerShell script to call the API and create a new deployment - https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusDeploy-Api/wiki/Deployments, or you could do it in the UI by creating a new release.

Comment: Okay, so I am guessing from reading the documentation, you can't initiate a deployment to a single machine.  Scenario: I spin up a newly provisioned server, I want just that server to call Octopus Deploy and get the latest package.  I don't think this is possible using the current API.

Comment: Perhaps a combination of calling this - *POST /api/deployments HTTP/1.1* -  plus checking the option of "Skip packages that are already installed" would mean that only the newly provisioned servers get updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip actions are step related, however I've just traced the POST request and there's a field SpecificMachineIds - So you CAN deploy to a specific machine.

It feels a bit smelly, but you'd have to get the new Id of the machine from the API, and then use that in your deployment request.

[image]

**EDIT**

A quick google on SpecificMachineIds and I have just come across this which is probably what you need

[Octopus Deploy Support Question](http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/4351-is-it-possible-to-deploy-on-a-single-machine-through-api)

Comment: This is absolutely my requirement, thank you very much.  It does indeed feel a bit dirty.  I've raised a question with Octopus Deploy directly.  Should probably be an environment wide setting to automatically push packages on discovery.

Comment: Yeah, I think that sounds like a nice feature - Suggest it here https://octopusdeploy.uservoice.com/forums/170787-general

Comment: Any future readers -https://octopusdeploy.uservoice.com/forums/170787-general/suggestions/8058177-environmental-setting-to-immediately-start-a-deplo